# Definition: Basis of a topology

Tags: general-topology, self-learning

I have a question regarding the basis of a topology, or actually 2 different definitions I encountered.
Munkres:
If $X$ is a set, a basis for a topology on $X$ is a collection $\mathscr{B} \subset P(X)$ such that:

i) For each $x \in X$, there is at least one basis element $B \in \mathscr{B}$ containing $x$.

ii) If x belongs to the intersection of two basis elements $B_1$ and $B_2$, then there is a basis element $B_3$ containing $x$ such that $B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$

And then he defines the generated topology as
$ \{ U \subset X \ | \ \forall x \in U \ : \exists B\in \mathscr{B} \ \ \text{s.t.} \ \ x \in B \subset U  \}$.

So this is basically a way to start with a collection of subsets of $X$ that fulfill those two properties and this collection will always be a basis for one topology on this set $X$.

In my class we started from the other direction, namely given a topological space $(X,\tau)$, $\mathscr{B} \subset P(X)$ is called a basis if every open set $U \in \tau$ can be written as an arbitrary union of basis elements.

On my latest exercise sheet, I have to proof that $\mathscr{B} \subset P(X)$ is the basis of a topology $\tau$ on $X$ (in the sense of the second definition) if and only if the two defining properties from Munkres definition hold.
The one direction of this is pretty easy by giving a constructive proof using the generated topology. In the other direction, I have to show that if one of those properties does not hold, there can not be a topology $\tau$ on $X$ such that $\mathscr{B} \subset P(X)$ is a basis of $\tau$. If the first property is violated, then $X$ cannot be written as a union of basis elements so this one is clear. However, in my understanding, I have a counterexample for the second one:

Let $X = \{1,2,3\}$ and $\tau = \{ \emptyset, X\}$ be the trivial topology. Now let $\mathscr{B}$ be such that it contains $B_1 = \{1,2\}$ and $B_2 = \{2,3\}$. To see that $\mathscr{B}$  is a basis, we have to check that we can generate $X$ as the union of basis elements which is clearly the case. However $B_1 \cap B_2 = \{ 2\}$ so property ii) is violated.

Now I obviously got something mixed up at some point but I am really not sure where so could somebody please clarify this for me?

Thanks,
Max

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. If $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and $\tau=\{\emptyset,X\}$, then $\tau$ has two basis and only two: $\{X\}$ and $\tau$. Of course that your sets $B_1$ and $B_2$ cannot belong to any basis of $\tau$, since $B_1,B_2\notin\tau$.

Comment: Okay, you are actually getting to the point of my confusion. You say that each basis element has to be in the topology itself. But does definition two really imply that? In my understanding, it only means that every element $U \in \tau $ has to be constructible as a union of basis elements, but not that every union of basis elements has to be in the topology. If we enforce that you are surely correct.

Comment: Your second definition is stated in a not very precise way. It should be: $U\in\tau$ if and only if $U$ can be expressed as an union of elements of $\mathcal B$. In particular, $\mathcal{B}\subset\tau$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second definition

> given a topological space $(X,\tau)$, $\mathscr{B}\subseteq P(X)$ is called a basis if every open set $U\in\tau$ can be written as an arbitrary union of basis elements.

is **incorrect**. It should be:

> given a topological space $(X,\tau)$, $\mathscr{B}\subseteq \tau$ is called a basis if every open set $U\in\tau$ can be written as an arbitrary union of basis elements.

Do you see the subtle yet major difference?

Note how bad your original definition is. According to it $P(X)$ is a basis for every possible topology.

Comment: Oh, you are so correct. And this is really how we defined it in class too and obviously breaks my counterexample. Thank you!

Comment: The first type of family where we can use any family of subsets is called a "network" for $X$. Spaces that are $T_3$ and have a countable network are called "cosmic spaces". A metrisable, or locally compact, cosmic space is second countable, i.e. has a countable base.